# I got problem when I rendering my character it only render my arm

Tags: rendering

Just only one object is rendered I'm using blender render and Version 2.79
[image]

Comment: on the top right panel, it looks like you've disabled the render for some objects ? (camera icon)

Comment: Sorry I new to blender but what ??

Comment: I see it now sorry